# CSS/HTML Vertical scrollbar goes passed the edge of window?

Tags: html, css

So I am working on a site and I having an issue. The scrollbar seems to extend passed the window. I cant see the bottom arrow even with max res. It is even worse when I resize the window. The main problem with this is that I can see my footer, but for some users with smaller screen resolutions cant. Here is my css:

```css
body {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:scroll; }
```

Here are screens of what I am talking  about:

full res: [fullres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxyEz.png)

Resized window: [resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvXvt.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `overflow:scroll;` from your body and put it on the specific div where you want the scroll to be

So your body css

```
body 
{
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome @jplanet anytime

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any position absolute or fixed in your code ? i dont see it as a problem just this short code. I would prefer "auto" over "scroll" for overflow property.

Comment: Yes. I have a few absolute's and fixed. I recently changed it from auto to scroll by recommendation.

Comment: it very difficult to tell without seeing the full code , if you using modal "fixed" will be more opt.